# How to query specific entities from Wikidata by ID using a SPARQL query?

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I need a SPARQL query returning a specific Wikidata ID or a list of IDs. In real life such query is useless but I need it for testing purposes.

The easiest variant I could come up with was:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?s
WHERE 
{
  ?s ?p ?o
  FILTER (?s = wd:Q151345).
}
```

I have to use `DISTINCT` because `?s ?p ?o` matches every triple within Q151345, if I omit it it output the item as many times as many property-value pairs it has.

Is there any easier way?

Comment: why not appending `LIMIT 1`? Not sure what the purpose of the query is? Just to check if there is any triple? And what means "easier"? In terms of what? IF you just want to check if there is a triple you could also use `ASK {wd:Q151345 ?p ?o}` which returns a boolean value.

Comment: Like I said the purpose is testing, I need to test some software on a specific result set rather than on a real-life one. But treat is more like a theoretical question (because my own solution actually reaches my goal). Easier == shorter, I was looking for a form like `{wd:Q151345 ?p ?o}` but I don't know how to bind the first element as a variable to output.

Comment: I mean, best practice for inline data since SPARQL 1.1 would be via `VALUES` clause: `select distinct ?s where {values ?s {wd:Q151345} ?s ?p ?o}` - but if this is "easier" for you I'm not sure. It's just the common way nowadays.

Comment: Or https://w.wiki/edH

Comment: @UninformedUser this was helpful, thanks, but why does it not work with list of values? I mean ii does output `?s` for each `?s ?p ?o` triple but this obviously duplicates `?s` many times. If I add `DISTINCT` it outputs nothing!

Comment: @StanislavKralin I did not know I can omit predicate and object. I removed the filter and this form seems to be the shortest! `select ?s {values ?s {wd:Q1 wd:Q2}}`.

Comment: That will return even `wd:QQQ`, though it is not present on Wikidata.

Comment: Yep, that's OK, it suitable for my goal.

Answer (score 3):

With the keyword VALUES, it's possible to use multiple instances.

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> 

SELECT ?s
WHERE 
{
  VALUES ?s {  wd:Q151345 wd:Q2996394  }
  ?s ?p ?o
}
LIMIT 10
```

Demo : http://linkedwiki.com/query/Query_multiple_instance_of_in_same_query

Doc: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data

Comment: This works, but it outputs `?s` multiple times, which is expected, but why does it output nothing if I add `DISTINCT`?

Comment: @greatvovan show me your query with the SPARQL endpoint... A query with DISTINCT and VALUES works also... see the demo in the message.

Comment: See https://w.wiki/ep$ This is essentially your query with `DISTINCT`.

Comment: @greatvovan Probably a bug in the database  https://w.wiki/f65

Answer (score 2):

@greatvovan You can try

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?s WHERE {
    SELECT ?s WHERE 
    {
        VALUES ?s {  wd:Q151345 wd:Q2996394  }
        ?s ?p ?o
    }
 }
```

Comment: `select ?s {values ?s {wd:Q1 wd:Q2}}`, in the comments.